# CSV writer also writing filename in error

Tags: java, csv, filewriter

Here's the code for my CSV writer:

```
public void writer(String firstName, String lastName, String phone) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(date() + ".csv");
        if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
            String csv = readWholesale(date() + ".csv");
            csv += "\n" + phone + "," + firstName + "," + lastName;
            FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(date() + ".csv", true);
            fwriter.write(csv);
            fwriter.flush();
            fwriter.close();
        }
        else {
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(date() + ".csv");
            fWriter.write(phone + "," + firstName + "," + lastName);
        }
        return;
```

Here's the sample output in the CSV:

```
2020-06-12.csv
1234567890,John,Doe2020-06-12.csv
1234567891,Jane,Doe
```

Any ideas as to why it would be doing this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also, here's the method readWholesale:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(path);
        String csv = "";
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            csv += scan.nextLine() + "\n";
        }
        csv = csv.substring(0, csv.length() - 1);
        return csv;
```

Comment: Obviously, in your `readWholesale` method you do not read the file contents - you just create a filename as a string and scan **this string** - then you append the filename and new entry to existing file.  That's it!

Comment: In fact, if you need just to append a line to existing file, you do not have to call `readWholesale` at all.  You should have used just `String csv = "\n" + phone + "," + firstName + "," + lastName;` and write to the file as is (`append` mode is enabled).

Comment: @AlexRudenko Ah, is this how it feels to be an idiot? Lol sorry wrote this on an absolute marathon of a coding session, thanks for the fresh set of eyes.